# Unit Testing IO Scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, scalatest

I'm starting unit testing in scala using scalatest.
the method I'm testing is as follows :

```
 def readAlpha: IO[Float] = IO {
    val alpha = scala.io.StdIn.readFloat()
    alpha
  }
```

The test consists of limiting the float that the user inserts to two decimals
Here is what I've tried but that doesn't seem to work.
How could I be fixing it

```
  "alpha" should " have two decimal numbers after comma" in {
    val alpha = readAlpha
    //assert(alpha == (f"$alpha%.2f"))
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot say that you are doing wrong, but you cannot compare effect type with a pure type. And It's not possible to write a direct test for the console input app. First of you should mock the `readAlpha` method somehow, then you should evaluate the value and after that, it's possible to compare them. Here is a small demonstration:

```
import cats.effect.IO

class ConsoleIO {
  def readAlpha: IO[Float] = IO {
    val alpha = scala.io.StdIn.readFloat()
    alpha
  }
}
// ---------------------------------

import cats.effect.{ContextShift, IO, Timer}
import org.scalatest.funsuite.AsyncFunSuite
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

class ConsoleIOTest extends AsyncFunSuite {

  class MockConsole extends ConsoleIO {
    override def readAlpha: IO[Float] = IO.pure(2.23f)
  }
  implicit val cs: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(ExecutionContext.global)
  implicit val timer: Timer[IO] = IO.timer(ExecutionContext.global)
  test("alpha should have two decimal numbers after comma") {
    val consoleIO = new MockConsole
    val alpha = consoleIO.readAlpha.unsafeRunSync()
    assert(alpha.toString === (f"$alpha%.2f"))
  }

}
```

Here `unsafeRunSync()` produces the result by running the encapsulated effects as impure.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'm a newbie and I see that it demands some advanced concepts isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, you can start from Advanced Scala with Cats if you have basic Scala knowledge

Comment: can you explain please the IO(pure(2.23f) in the MockConsole Class ?

Comment: IO.pure receives only pure value. 2.23f is just x floating number, it can be anything but should respect the return type of the method. Imagine that, you enter 2.23 from console when you asked to enter a float number. Instead of  `StdIn.readFloat()` we put a number. You can try to Google subtyping and mocking in Scala. And also about effects types such as Future, cats.effect IO, ZIO, Monix Task...

Comment: sorry for my question but I'm getting Expected :"2,32"
Actual   :2.32 !!

Comment: You can check it here: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Bunyod/LYbacOMhR5KvUeCzuVTYWg/8